# If "a" has a mult. inverse, and "b" has a mult. inverse, then ab has a mult. inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I've been reviewing some stuff for modular arithmetic and I got stuck on this part:

Consider a, b in mod n. Prove that if a has a multiplicative inverse and b has a multiplicative inverse, then ab has a multiplicative inverse.

What I did was:

Let c, d be multiplicative inverses to a and b, respectively. ac = 1. bd = 1. Therefore, ab(cd) = 1. So, ab has a multiplicative inverse.

Is this correct? If not, where should I expand on? I know it seems like a stupid question, but modular arithmetic has always been a pain for me. Thank you!

Comment: This works only when the operation is commutative. What works in general is to note that $(ab)(dc)=a(bd)c=ac=1$, so $dc$ is multiplicative inverse to $ab$.

Comment: If OP’s working exclusively in $\Bbb Z/(n)$, it’s not a problem.

Comment: For form sake one should become familiar with the result $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$  it make sense, is darn near universal, and it's pretty to boot.  In this case it doesn't matter, and the op did a very good job of intelligent thinking, but in general assuming commutivity and not applying directly tip to tip, is the type of sloppy thinking that can hurt one later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicative inverse for $ab$ is $b^{-1}a^{-1}$. (It is straightforward to verify).

Comment: Ah, I see where I was confused, I didn't consider associativity and the identity element. Thank you!